# MySQL as a data source to Wordpress

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Can we use MySQL tables as a data source for WordPress?  (different tables with WP database itself)
I want to use my own tables and show them through WordPress web.

Comment: Even if you couldn't, you'd still have iframes, right?

Comment: The answer is yes, you can.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You can use the global variable of wordpress database object $wpdb to run any database queries with the custom tables.

Ref link: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb